# UPDATE SCRIPT added to an existing select script - how do you select and then update in one script>

Tags: mysql

I have a select statement that looks at two tables and returns lines from T1 if there are no FAIL results in T2. This is an inspection tool. T1 is the inspection and T2 is the details of the inspection. Each inspection in T1 has 25 inspection points or detail lines in T2 any of the 25 detail lines in T2 can fail and then must be addressed.

The code below works great and returns the data I want the way I want it - it returns only those inspections from T1 that don't have any detail lines in a fail state. So in a group of inspections I am looking at, there are total 1076 inspections of which 309 have at least 1 line in a fail state, so this script returns 767 inspection lines - these inspections all can be closed.

Now I would like to expand this out a bit And update all the lines that are returned with a new status of closed. These lines are returned because they don't have a fail on any detail line and thus the inspection would be complete. I want to find those lines and then update the status to complete all in one script run.

I don't know how to do that (novice SQL scripter) - Any help would be most appreciated.

```
    SELECT  t1.* 
FROM t1
WHERE 
    t1.INSP_TYPE = 'room_CHECKLIST'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM t2 
        WHERE t2.insp_no = t1.insp_no
        AND t2.result ='fail'
    )
```

Comment: Try not to confuse "script" with "query"/"statement". SQL generally talks in terms of queries/statements, not "scripts", as those are what application code is written in (e.g. PHP or JSP, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much to change in your query. I guess you want

```
UPDATE t1 
SET t1.status = 'closed'
WHERE 
    t1.INSP_TYPE = 'room_CHECKLIST'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM t2 
        WHERE t2.insp_no = t1.insp_no
        AND t2.result ='fail'
    )
```